# Got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, swing

I am getting time, value, weights from database and related methods are available in ExperimenalImpl. The values are displayed in a table. when we select particular row, the related getXxx()method will call. But some rows are getting data properly. only one row given this exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
            at com.integrativebioinformatics.processdb.pdbnt.IBExperimentalDataImpl.getWeights(IBExperimentalDataImpl.java:103)
            at com.insilicalabs.processdb.ui.controllers.ExperimentalDataController.showExperiment(ExperimentalDataController.java:197)
            at com.insilicalabs.processdb.ui.controllers.ExperimentalDataController.showExperimentAtIndex(ExperimentalDataController.java:184)
```

Code:

```
    public void setWeights(double[] experimentWeigths) {
            if (experimentWeigths == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot take a null argument");
            this.experimentWeigths = new double[experimentWeigths.length];
            System.arraycopy(experimentWeigths, 0, this.experimentWeigths, 0, experimentWeigths.length);
            for(int i=0;i<this.experimentWeigths.length;i++){
                System.out.println("Weights : "+ experimentWeigths[i]);
            }
        }


public double[] getWeights() {
        double[] newWeights = new double[this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length];
        if(this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length != 0){
            System.arraycopy(this.experimentWeigths, 0, newWeights, 0, this.experimentWeigths.length);//Here, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occured.

            for (int i = this.experimentWeigths.length; i < this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length; ++i) {
                newWeights[i] = (0.0D / 0.0D);
            }
        }   

        return newWeights;
    }


    public double[][] getTimeValuePairs() {
            double[][] newPairs = new double[2][this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length];
            System.arraycopy(this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0], 0, newPairs[0], 0, this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length);
            System.arraycopy(this.experimentTimeValuePairs[1], 0, newPairs[1], 0, this.experimentTimeValuePairs[1].length);

            return newPairs;
        }


public double[][] getTimeValuePairs() {
        double[][] newPairs = new double[2][this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length];
        System.arraycopy(this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0], 0, newPairs[0], 0, this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length);
        System.arraycopy(this.experimentTimeValuePairs[1], 0, newPairs[1], 0, this.experimentTimeValuePairs[1].length);
        System.out.println("Called getTimeValuePairs() from IBExperimentalDataImpl : "+this.experimentTimeValuePairs);
        return newPairs;
    }
```

Comment: -1 After 4 questions, you should know how to format your questions properly.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is a pretty clear exception. Somewhere you are using a index which is outside an array bounds. You must learn to debug such simple exceptions and errors on your own, if you have any ambitions as a programmer.

Comment: `newWeights[i] = (0.0D / 0.0D);` Damn, that's evil:P

Comment: in addition to all comments, please at least post an SSCCE. If we could run your code without loosing so much time a quick answer will be possible.

Comment: I agree with @PetarMinchev , this is a pretty clear, straight forward bug.  Also, `(0.0D/0.0D)`, please don't do that, lol :-)

Answer (score 3):

You allocate `newWeights` array with this length `this.experimentTimeValuePairs[0].length`,

but in `arrayCopy` you are using `this.experimentWeigths.length`.

You should, probably, allocate `newWeights` with `this.experimentWeigths.length`, because that is what you are copying.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [System.ArrayCopy API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29), it says:

```
Otherwise, if any of the following is true, an IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown and the destination is not modified:

The srcPos argument is negative.
The destPos argument is negative.
The length argument is negative.
srcPos+length is greater than src.length, the length of the source array.
destPos+length is greater than dest.length, the length of the destination array.
```

I would start by debugging your program and seeing which of these situations occur.